# What is the definition of plethysm in the representation theory of permutation groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, permutation-groups, plethysm

Let $s_\lambda \circ s_\mu$ be a plethysm. Here let $\lambda, \mu$ be $m,n$ box Young diagrams.

I have seen the definition of plethysms in symmetric functions. I would like to understand the corresponding realisation of plethysms as the regular representations of the permutation group, in this case $S_{mn}$.

If possible can you please explain this in a way a physicist can understand?

Comment: For the symmetric group, the representation theoretic significance of plethysm is related to wreath products. See Theorem A2.8 of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol 2. (By the way, plethysm has a different representation-theoretic significance for the general linear group; and that one is probably a bit easier to understand- it is composition of characters).

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for your reference. I have difficulty trying to understand wreath products, can you perhaps give an elementary example how this works or some reference?

Comment: Example A2.9 in EC2 is a good example, imo.